# How to make a redirect in velocity template?

Tags: apache, tomcat, velocity

How to redirect to `http://google.com` in the code `.vm` file?  (I mean within
`#if <redirect to Google here> #else ...  #end` statement)

Doing
    setRequestURI('http://google.com')
or similar doesn't work and I'm not sure if it is possible at all.

Thank you.

Can anybody explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO a template is the wrong place to implement logic like this. You should determine upfront (in whatever you do - you don't mention your environment other than velocity), *before* you determine that the velocity template in question should render the output.

Once you're in the template, you can't assume that you're within a web browser (it might render an email message) or that you have access to the response headers (the template might be rendered as part of a page when the response has already been "committed", e.g. the headers are already sent to the browser.

Do yourself a favor and move the logic further up the chain, out of your velocity template. If you need a quick fix: render Javascript that triggers the redirect. But pay back this technical debt sooner rather than later.